# Best OAuth 2.0 practice for Java

Tags: java, api, rest, oauth-2.0

I have been asked to make an `OAuth 2.0` integration with an external company. All of our `REST APIs` are written in `Java` and I was hoping someone could direct me to an example of how this implementation is suggested these days.